# Vector3.MoveTowards is not doing its thing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Plank unable to move when i used Vector3.MoveTowards method. I am not entirely sure why. Anyone kind enough to have a look?

```
public class BrickMoveVErtical : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector3 positionOne, positiontwo, nextposition;
    public Transform plankTranform;
    public Transform positionBTransform;
    public float speed;

    void Start () 
    {
        positionOne  = plankTranform.localPosition;
        positiontwo  = positionBTransform.localPosition;
        nextposition = positiontwo;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        move();
    }
    private void move() 
    {
       plankTranform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(positionOne,nextposition,Time.deltaTime*speed);
       if(Vector3.Distance(plankTranform.localPosition,nextposition)<0.1)
           changeMovementPlank();
    }
    void changeMovementPlank() 
    {
        nextposition = nextposition != positionOne ? positionOne : positiontwo;
    }                        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the current position as the `current` argument:

```
plankTranform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(plankTranform.localPosition, nextposition,Time.deltaTime*speed);
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Same goes for the uses of the `positiontwo` variable. Use the transform directly or you get stale values.

Comment: @Nico thanks for your comment but isn't the first parameter of `Vector3.MoveToward` method is initial point? In that case i have already initialize positionOne  inside start method.

Comment: @Esla correct. But you are moving the object bit by bit every frame. If you always use the starting point, your object will move a little bit from the starting point each frame (ie, getting nowhere really), instead of a little bit further and further every frame.

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg Thankyou, that make sense now i ran into another problem. When speed is set to too high, the character automatically jumps in the air when plank goes vertically up. Any idea how to turn off physics of plank so character behave normally on moving planks?

Answer (score 0):

This one of the same mistakes you just made in the last question. `Vector3` is a value type, which means if you do this:

```
private v1 = new Vector3(3, 3);
private v2 = v1;         // v2 has now *copied* the value of v1
v1 = new Vector(0, 0);   // v1 is now (0, 0), but v2 is still (3, 3)
```

What you're doing is effectively that. If you want a variable-like thing that will always give the latest value, use a property, like this:

```
public Vector3 positionOne
{
    get { return plank.transform.position;  }
    set { plank.transform.position = value; }
}
```

This will always return the correct and updated value and when you set this you will actually change the original value, not the copy.

Comment: i know the variable how the variable work but get set property is completely new to me. i am now digging more into it. Anyways This question is about something else. I was confused about  `Vector3.MoveTowards()` initial parameter. Now my doubts are cleared up. Thanks for your answer anyways.